# MediaPlayer/Mediaplayer.h file not found

Tags: objective-c, video, media-player

I am trying to play a video in my ViewController. Mediaplayer.framework and all the Headers are in my Frameworks folder, including the MediaPlayer.h file. But when I put

```
#import "TutorialViewController.h"
#import <MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h>

@interface TutorialViewController ()

@end

@implementation TutorialViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

    MPMoviePlayerController *player =
    [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]
     initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:url]];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     addObserver:self
     selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];

    //---play movie---
    [player play];
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void) movieFinishedCallback:(NSNotification*) aNotification {
    MPMoviePlayerController *player = [aNotification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     removeObserver:self
     name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
     object:player];


// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:        (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

in my .m file, I get an error stating 'MediaPlayer/MediaPlayer.h' file not found. 
What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but this is an objective c question? Perhaps you should tag it as such

Comment: Yes, it is. Sorry I am new to all of this; how do I add a tag after I've posted the question?

Comment: You should be able to edit the post. You might have to also, since I think you need more info. I added your tag but I think you may also need to post your file structure. The obvious thing would be to make sure that directory exists as expected Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/Headers/MediaPlayer.h and that they have been linked tot he project properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Removing the framework from the project and re-adding it should solve this problem. What I would recommend you do is open your project's directory and make sure that when you adding the framework to your project you only referenced the framework and didn't copy it. If the framework exists within your project folder then delete it, otherwise just remove it's reference from your project.

Then navigate to:

> Project Navigator>>Your apps target>>Summary Tab(scrolled to bottom)

Click the "+" under "Linked Frameworks" and from here you can re-add the reference to the framework to your project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hope some of the above solutions worked for other people ... unfortunately they didn't work for me on this occasion

BUT ... this did work for me ... it is a little bit "hacky" but it got the project building again (and I might just hit my deadline now)

I used the absolute full path to the header file I needed , e.g.

```
    #import "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS6.1.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/MediaPlayer.framework/Headers/MediaPlayer.h"
```

This got rid of that pesky !exclamation mark "File not found".  I will continue to investigate the reason as this clearly points to some paths issue in xCode

Answer (score 0):

I believe the OP was missing the `UIKit` include. That's what happened to me. It gives the same error as described above even though the framework has been included in the project.